# Symfony 3.4 getDoctrine() results in error

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have seen some posts about this topic but not the answer I am looking for. When I call `$this->getDoctrine();` from a method say `public function returnObjectAction(){}` and the Class implements `use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` it results in container == 0. I also tried `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` and this also ends with the error "Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."
Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FslyL.jpg)

Comment: post your controller please. and use back-quotes when posting code, not double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Check your controller extends `Controller` ( in addition to the `use` ), this way:

```
class YourController extends Controller {}
```

And that you have `doctrine/orm` and `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` in the `require` part of your composer.json

Add them if it's missing.

Run a `composer install`

Answer (score -1):

doctrine is available in `composer.json`. Both are in required section.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;

use AppBundle\Entity\AppConnector;
use AppBundle\Repository\AppConnectorRepository;

class AppController extends Controller {

        public $s_mch = '';
        public $s_headers = '';
        public $s_data = '';
        public $s_response = '';

        public $o_results = '';
        public $s_results = '';

        public $s_url = '';
        public $s_cid = '';
        public $s_url_prefix = '';
        public $s_url_suffix = '';

        protected $s_user = '';
        protected $s_apikey = '';
        protected $s_server = '';
        public $s_klant = '';
        public $s_request_type = '';

    /**
     * @Route('/app-index')
     */
    public function indexAction() {

    }

    public function returnObjectAction($klant='',$url_suffix='',$cid='',$request_type='GET') {

        $this->s_klant = $klant;
        $this->s_cid = $cid;
        $this->s_url_suffix = $url_suffix;
        $this->s_request_type = $request_type;

        $klant_info = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
              // ->getRepository(AppConnector::class)
              // ->find($this->s_klant);

           // if (!$klant_info) {
           //     throw $this->createNotFoundException(
           //         'Geen informatie gevonden voor klant: '.$this->s_klant
           //     );
           // }

        /*
         * 28 april 2018 - 9:10 AM
         * --
        */
        $this->s_url = 'https://' . $this->s_server . '.' . $this->s_url_suffix;

        if($this->s_request_type == 'GET')
            $s_mch = curl_init();
            $s_headers = array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($this->s_user . ':' . $this->s_apikey)
            );
            curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->s_url);
            curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $s_headers);
            curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $this->s_request_type); 
            curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

            if($this->s_request_type != 'GET') {
                curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($s_mch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($this->s_data) ); // send data in json
            }
            $this->s_response = curl_exec($s_mch);
            if ($this->s_response === false) {
                throw new Exception('curl_exec returned false: ' . trigger_error(curl_error($s_mch)));
            }
            $this->o_results = json_decode($this->s_response);

        return $this->o_results;
    }

}
```